# JUnit: EasyMock static method call from abstract class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock

I have an abstract class with static methods

```
public abstract class AbstractClass{
   ...

   public static void staticMethod(...) {
      ...
   }

   ...
}
```

then i have a class which is calling a static method from the abstract class

```
public void isSatisifiedBy(...){
   ...
   AbstractClass.staticMethod(...);
   ...
}
```

I want to completely mock out this class (or this classes method calls) so that when i am testing the `isSatisifiedBy` method all the code in the method runs like on live except the calls to the `AbstractClass` as this will be mocked out.

Is there a way of doing this using `EasyMock`?

Comment: Is `isSatisfiedBy` a method in `AbstractClass` and you want to mock its calls to static methods is `AbstractClass`?

Comment: no the `isSatisfiedBy` method is in a completely different class